# call the browser from cmd and pass the content as parameter

Tags: cmd

How to call the browser (iexplorer ) from cmd.exe and pass the content (string included html tegs) as parameter. After open browser it must show page
Is it possibly ?

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you explain what tegs are? I suppose you mean tags, but that does not make sense as you simply seem to want to open a URL? `start "" iexplore www.google.com`

Comment: i iave a string like '<html>
<head>
 <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>INFO</h1></center>
<br/><br/>

<br/><br/>
<font style="color:green">GREEN</font>
<br/><br/>
<b>BOLD</b>
<br/><br/>

<br/><br/>
<hr>
MATERIAL
<a href=http://zarabotat-na-sajte.ru/>
link</a> 
<br/><br/>
GOODBY
</body>
</html>' and i want to open browser from cmd and pass this string as parametr. This is not an URL. It is HTML CODE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the URL as a parameter than it is possible but there is no any parameter which accepts HTML tags.

Example:

```
start "" iexplore.exe <URL>
```

References:

(1) [IE Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85))

(2) [Command Line arguments in Internet Explorer on Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/command-line-arguments-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: `start "" iexplore <url>`

Comment: the double quotes are important as cmd will recognise the first double quote set as title, if you do not add it and anything else uses double quotes, it could cause errors.